# Entity Framework can't run stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework for the first time. It's a simple application that looks up part numbers and displays them in a grid. My application runs fine locally, but when I execute against the production SQL Server database, the pages that have stored procedure calls with Entity Framework fail.

However, it will run an Entity Framework call to a table and return the data, but not a stored procedures. I do this to populate a drop down list and it works fine. When I call the stored procedure to return the search results, it fails.

Could this be a setting on the production SQL Server that my user ID does not have access to execute stored procedures?

Here is the error message from the log:

> Date/Time: 12/7/2013 12:23:41 PM
>
> Title: Error
>   Message: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>   StackTrace:
>   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
>   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateFunctionObjectResult[TElement](EntityCommand entityCommand, ReadOnlyMetadataCollection`1 entitySets, EdmType[] edmTypes, MergeOption mergeOption)
>
>   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction[TElement](String functionName, MergeOption mergeOption, ObjectParameter[] parameters)
>
>   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction[TElement](String functionName, ObjectParameter[] parameters)
>
>   at FanInfo.FandbEntities1.uspFANSearch(String idParm, Nullable`1 diaFromParm, Nullable`1  diaToParm, Nullable`1 hubFromParm, Nullable`1 hubToParm) in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Projects\Fan Info\Fan Info\Model1.Designer.vb:line 201
>   at FanInfo.frmMain.LoadSearchResults() in C:\Users\Public\Documents\Projects\Fan Info\Fan Info\Main.vb:line 208

Comment: Did you see the inner exception for details?

Comment: It says "See the inner exception for details." Doing that would save you the trouble of asking a question.

Answer (score 1):

Since it Works locally but not in Production. The error will be related to the difference between these. Normally this is:

- Rights
- Incorrect Connection string
- Firewall problems

In Your case Access to tables Works. The problem is therefore a rights issue.

You need "Execute" right on the stored procedures.

See: [GRANT EXECUTE to all stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321334/grant-execute-to-all-stored-procedures)

**Edit**

Based on Your comment there are two possibilities:

- The Connection to the SQL Server is not using the Security id that you think it is using. Check the Connection string. Also is the code running as a Windows Application or under IIS?
- The other thing is, is the stored procedures in different schema on the prod database than on the dev database.

**Edit 2**

Based on Your last comment, there was a difference in the structure of Your stored procedure in Your Development environment and in Production.

Comment: I used the Grant Execute to the stored procedures for the user ID.  I also tried restarting the sql server.  It still did not resolve the problem.  When I go to SQL Server Studio and sign in using the ID, the stored procedure works fine.  When I execute via Entity Framework, it fails.  I checked the setting on my local SQL Server ID and the login/security/roles match locally and prod.  Any other suggestions.  Is there another setting in SQL Server that I'm missing.  The direct access to a table still works fine.

Comment: Ok.  Its an issue with Entity Framework.  I create a temp method that calls the stored procedure.  It returns everything fine within my app.  So I can call the stored procedure without Entity Framework, but when I call a stored procedure within Entity Framework it fails on production.  Works fine on my development machine that I used to create the model.

Comment: I rebuilt my app on the client machine and updated My complex function.  It worked

Comment: @user2011126 If this answer solves your problem please accept this as answer, it will be help full for future visitors